# How can I use mongoDB efficiently in this scenario?

Tags: performance, mongodb, query-performance

I'm trying to build a system of documents that have hundreds of tags assigned to them, but each document-tag association has a certain condition it has to also meet so the document would be returned:

```
{
title: "new document", 
tags: [
    {
    label: "label1", 
    intervals: [
       {start_date: "2012-01-05", end_date: "2013-01-05"},
       {start_date: "2012-01-06", end_date: "2013-01-25"},
    ], 
    applicable_for: ["birthdays","anniversaries"]
    },
    {
    label: "label2", 
    start_date: "2012-04-05", 
    end_date: "2014-02-05", 
    applicable_for: ["anniversaries"]
    }
]
};
```

A typical search would be something like:

Show me documents tagged with "label1", but only if this tag is applicable for "birthdays" and a certain date interval D0-D1 overlaps with one of the tag's intervals.

I have two questions:

- can this type of query be performed in MongoDB?
- is MongoDB the correct choice for this scenario? I've never used it until now, but it sems a better fit than MySQL or SOLR for tens of thousands of documents, each with hundreds of tags.

Thanks in advance!